# Azure Storage Account logging

Tags: azure, logging, storage, azure-storage-account

i didn't find on azure portal but is possible to get from an azure storage account the log for which users or application access, write or do everithing inside a blob container e relative folders, file share, queues and table?

thanks

Comment: I'd start by taking a look at Azure Storage Analytics.

Comment: ok thank you i will try to read it